# Why isn't the value of ind = index1() || index2(); where index1() = undefined and index2() = 0 equal to 0 but undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I have a function concat() that takes to generator functions from some start to some end, and serves as another generator by combining the two generators. For example, if the first generator function generates a number from 0 to 2, and the second from 0 to 1, the concat() generates (0, 1, 2, 0, 1) for later calls undefined. After implementing concat(), when tested, it returns (0, 1, 2, 1) for later calls undefined. It skips the first generated value of the second generator function.

I have changed the way I have implemented and it works but I don't understand why it doesn't work for another. I have tried to print immediate results of the return and I have found 0 is skipped because the second generator and first generator returns when put in OR operation give undefined for the first value of second generator as pointed out by the console.log i put before returning. I don't know why that is the case.
The multiline-commented code works as expected. What is different between the two?

```js
const from = (start) => {
  return () => {
    const next = start;
    start += 1;
    return next;
  };
};
const to = (fromIndex, end) => {
  return () => {
    const at = fromIndex();
    if (at < end) {
      return at;
    }
    return undefined;
  };
};
const fromTo = (start, end) => {
  return to(from(start), end);
};
const concat = (index1, index2) => {
  return () => {
    let ind = index1() || index2();

    // console.log(ind);
    return ind;

    /*
    
    // THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED: 

       ind = index1();
       if (ind !== undefined) {
         return ind;
       }
       ind = index2();
       if (ind !== undefined) {
         return ind;
       }
       */

  };
};

const con = concat(fromTo(0, 3), fromTo(0, 2));

console.log('con(): ', con()); // 0
console.log('con(): ', con()); // 1
console.log('con(): ', con()); // 2
console.log('con(): ', con()); // 1 but expecting 0
console.log('con(): ', con()); // undefined but expecting 1
```

I expected a print in the console like:

```
        con(): 0
        con(): 1
        con(): 2
        con(): 1 // but expecting 0
        con(): undefined // but expecting 1
```

Comment: [Seems like the OR works correctly](https://jsbin.com/fowocuqute/edit?js,console) but you're not actually getting `0` when you expect that, it's `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, i am getting undefined. Why is that?

Comment: Because `index1()` and `index2()` return `undefined`. I've not checked how they work or what they are supposed to do, though. You seem to be in a better position to know about them.

Comment: @VLAZ I know they both return undefined. Why does the second generator's value return undefined while it is suppose to return 0? Everything works in the multiline commented section, what is different?

Comment: `0` is false so it will go to the next index. If you would have started at `1` it would have not been asking this question.

Comment: Ah, *damn*. That's my fault there. And maybe related to your bug? When you call `index1() || index2()` and `index1()` returns anything that's not a zero, then `index2` will not be invoked. When I restructured the code to log the values, it's not calling each function every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a truthy check

when you call `index1()` returns `0`. And you have an or. Problem here is the or says "`0` is not truthy" so move to `index2()`

So you can not just do that simple check and hence why your other version works. Closest you can get would be something like this.

```
const concat = (index1, index2) => {
  return () => {
    const ind = index1()
    return ind !== undefined ? ind : index2()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i checked the truth value with Boolean(undefined || 0) which gives false. I didn't think it would get false then assign undefined. I was expecting assignment of 0.

Comment: is this assumption right: 

const a = undefined || false; // equivalent to ignore undefinde, ignore false, no assignment so assign undefined? 

so a = undefined ?

Comment: `a` would be `false`, if first item is not a truthy value, it uses the next item. ["If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr1; else, returns expr2."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)